# How to use uvm_test_done objection in test sequence?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I am doing following in my UVM testbench to create seq and start test.

1. I've some sequences. I'm copying a code snippet from one of the sequences bellow.

Inside body():

```
`uvm_create_on(my_seq, p_sequencer.my_sequencer)
my_seq.randomize();
`uvm_send(my_seq)
```

2.In my test, I'm doing following to start a sequence:

```
   task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
     ..... 
     phase.raise_objection(this);
     seq.start(env.virtual_sequencer);
     phase.drop_objection(this);
    endtask
```

Now, if I do this, the test is starts and ends at zero time. What I mean is, the DUT is not being driven by my sequence. If I make following change then it seems to work fine:

Option1:changing run_phase in test-

```
   task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
     ..... 
     phase.raise_objection(this);
     seq.start(env.virtual_sequencer);
     #100000;   // Adding delay here. 
     phase.drop_objection(this);
    endtask
```

If I do this then test starts and I can see that DUT is being driven and everything is working as expected. However, test always ends at time 1000000- even though the sequence is not done sending all the transactions to DUT. It's not good as I don't know how long my DUT will take to complete a test. So, I rather tried something like this:

Option 2: Keeping the default code in test (not adding delay in run_phase). Making following change inside body of my_seq:

Inside body():

```
 uvm_test_done.raise_objection(this);
`uvm_create_on(my_seq, p_sequencer.my_sequencer)
 my_seq.randomize();
`uvm_send(my_seq)
 uvm_test_done.drop_objection(this);
```

If I do this then it works fine. Is it the proper way of handling objection ? Going back to my original implementation, I assumed that my sequence is blocking. So, whenever I start a sequence in run_phase of test using start(...), it'll be considered as blocking and will wait at that line until sequence is done sending all the transaction. So, I didn't add any delay in my original code.

I think I'm missing something here. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Calling `seq.start(...)` should block. As a starting point, add a debug print in your test and check that this is the case.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I have a feeling that you are doing a `fork...join_none` in your main sequence.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing fork...join_none in my sequence. Is it a bad practice to use objections like this inside sequences? I added this raise/drop objections in my base sequence. As all my sequences are extended from base sequence, by default objection is being applied to all of them.

Comment: It depends on who you ask. The guys from Mentor Graphics recommend that you just raise objections in your test and not in your sub-sequences or other components because of the performance benefit associated to propagating objections throughout the hierarchy. I wrote an answer; look at that for some thoughts on forking. If you can't implement anything like that, then just leave the objections in your sub-sequences, it should be fine, albeit with a small potential performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a fork in your main sequence, then its `body()` task (which is called by `start()`) won't block. If you need to do a `fork...join_none` due to some kind of synchronization you need, you should also implement some kind of mechanism to know when the forked off processes terminate so that you can stall body until then. Example:

```
// inside your main sequence
event forked_finished;

task body();
  fork
    `uvm_do(some_sub_seq)
    -> forked_finished;
  join_none
  // do some other stuff here in parallel

  // make sure that the forked processes also finished
  @forked_finished;
endtask
```

This code here assumes that the forked process finishes after your other code does. In production code you probably wouldn't rely on this assumption and would use a `uvm_event` to test first if the event already triggered before waiting.

Because `body()` waits until everything is finished w.r.t. stimulus, then you shouldn't have any problem setting and objection before starting this sequence and the lowering it once it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You really have to consider the semantics of your sequence. Usually I expect a sequence's body to not complete until it is finished. So doing a fork/join_none would be undesirable because the caller of the sequence would have a way of knowing that the sequence has completed. Similar to what you see in your test.

The solution is to not have my_seq::body return until it is complete.

If the caller of my_seq needs to do something in parallel with my_seq, then it should be their responsibility to do the appropriate fork.